# Cannot launch Tkinter window from VSCode, but can from IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I am starting work learning how to design a GUI, I have used VS for everything, and love it. However i cannot figure out how to launch a tkinter widow from VS. I can from IDLE just fine, I saw on another thread that one should add... window.mainloop().... to the code, because IDLE does that for you. I tried that and still no luck. Please let me know how to proceed. I am fairly new to Python and am lost. [Here is an image of my code and terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCSRR.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error directly in the question. Pictures aren't searchable and can't be read at all by the visually impaired.

Comment: I only see a warning. What's the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal i saw that you are on a Mac computer. Mac has a version of python with it from the start. The problem probably comes from there.
The code you have works fine.

IDLE comes with python so it can find the correct version.
You should find an option in VSCode settings to change the python interpreter.

EDIT:
I imagine that VSCode is importing the python version 2.7 tkinter.
Maybe you can use a virtualenv with VSCode and just move the tkinter version you want to use into the virtualenv's lib. Not sure if that works.

Comment: When i click on the bottom left, i am using Python 3.8.2 64-Bit.... However my second option was Python 2.7.16 (which i was able to launch a window with!)... any idea how i can change it so i can use a python 3.x version?